# JavaScript jQuery - Problem with checkbox styled into power button and updating its state when reload webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, plc

Currently I'm doing a project: control motor through webpage. My webpage will send data to a S7 1200 PLC which then will control the motor. This is how my webpage looks like:

[image]

When I click on the power button, it will send data to PLC (if it send 1 then PLC starts the motor else the motor will stop. The power button is a checkbox type, I style it to look like a button using css.

This is the html code for the power button in my main file `index.html`:

```
<tr>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:justify" id ="start"> START MOTOR                        
        </th>
        <th class="button off"><span class = "fa fa-power-off"></span><input type="checkbox" id='"webdata".Start'/>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

This is html code to show the status of motor if it's running or not:

```
<tr>
        <th align="left" style="text-align:justify">STATUS:                 
        </th>
        <th id="Status_Run">STOP                        
        </th>   
    </tr>
```

This is my css to style the power button:

```
.button {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        height: 55px;
        width: 55px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 3px rgb(34,34,34), 
                    0px 7px 20px 3px rgb(17,17,17), 
                    inset 0px 4px 2px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2), 
                    inset 1px -9px 35px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        background-color: rgb(83,87,93);
        top: 1px;
        //color: #fff;
        //text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgb(250,250,250);
        outline: none;
        left: -13px;
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transition: 0.5s;

    } 
    .button input[type=checkbox] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;

    }

    .button.on {
        width: 55px;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 55px;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
        //-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #F83953, inset 0 6px 1px 1px rgba(144, 59, 59,1);
        transform: translate3d(-2px,3px,0);
        transition: 0.5s;
        //top: -2px;
        background-color: rgb(83,87,93);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34), 
                    0px 3px 7px 0px rgb(17,17,17), 
                    inset 0px 0px 0px 3px cyan, 
                    inset 0px -10px 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

    }

    .button .fa {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #0c0c0c;
    }

    .button.on .fa {

        color: aqua;  
        text-shadow:  0px 0px 20px #ffffff, 
                      0px -3px 30px #01bbf8;
        }
```

This is Jquery code to send data to the PLC:

```
           var checkbox;
            nodes.forEach(function buttonStatus (buttonControl) {
                if (buttonControl.className == ("button on")) {
                    buttonControl.lastElementChild.checked = true;

                }
                buttonControl.addEventListener("click", function toggleSwitch() {
                    if (buttonControl.className === "button on") {
                        buttonControl.className = 'button off';
                    } else {
                        buttonControl.className = ("button on");
                    }

                    checkbox = buttonControl.lastElementChild;
                    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
                    url="IO.htm";
                    var ival = +checkbox.checked;
                    var sdata = checkbox.id;
                    //alert(ival);                      
                    sdata=escape(sdata)+'='+ival;
                    alert(sdata);

                    $.post(url,sdata,function(result,status){});

                }, false);
                });
```

When I click on the power button, the `class = "button off"` turns into `class = "button on"` the power button is glowing like what I style it.  It will send a request to the IO.htm file. The request looks like this: `%22webdata.Start%22=1`.

This is IO.htm:

```
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"webdata".Start' --> {"Status" : ":="webdata".Start:"}
```

The `<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"webdata".Start' -->` allows me to write data to the tag name "webdata".Start in the PLC. If I send a request `%22webdata.Start%22=1` to this IO.htm file then the tag "webdata".Start in PLC will modify to 1 then the motor start running. The `:="webdata".Start:` allows me to see the status of the tag "webdata".Start. If motor is running, then `"Status" : 1`.

This is jQuery code to update status of motor to my index.html file:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   setInterval(function() { 
   url="IO.htm";
   $.getJSON(url, function(result){
                            if(result["Status"]==0) {
                            $('#Status_Run').text("STOP");
                            }
                            else {
                            $('#Status_Run').text("RUNNING");
                            }
                        });
                    },1000);
```

If the Status is 1 then in the `<th id="Status_Run"> </th>` will show Running, else it will show Stop.

My problem is when I click the power button, the button glowing, the Status show Running and the motor that connected to PLC, is running too. When I reload my webpage, `class = "button on"` now returns to `class = "button off"`, the Status still show running of course, motor still running. All I want is when I reload my webpage, the power button must remain its glowing state while the status showing Running. I can't find a solution.

Comment: You could have been more objective explaining your problem at once and them giving the background information on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use session storage to keep your state, on of off. This way it won't reset until you restart your browser. For example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("state", "off");

$(".button").on("click", function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("state") == "off") {
    sessionStorage.setItem("state", "on");
    $(this).removeClass("off");
    $(this).addClass("on");
  } else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("state", "off");
    $(this).removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("off");
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is okay for the problem here, but doing it would still fail if Pep Oversea tried to close and reopen the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CSS class names have to come in a single word, `button on` and `button off` are three different class names `button` and `on` / `off` with `button` being repeated on both cases. You should have used `button-off` and `button-on` instead.

With that said, when the page loads it is being "drawn" with the `button-off` style as default:

```css
<th class="button-off"><span class = "fa fa-power-off"></span><input type="checkbox" id='"webdata".Start'/>
```

You need to create a function that will run right after the page finishes loading and that will call the function to check the motor status. After checking the motor status you should automatically update the state of your button`s checkbox accordingly to the motor's status.

Comment: I've written a function that updates motor's status. If motor is on then this function will add "button-on" to the class. I tried to reload my page. I can say it worrked because button still glowing while motor was running. But when I clicked on button to turn it off, I had to click twice. It happens evertime I reload the page.